# Add a Column that Represents a Concatenation of Two Other Varchar Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an employees table and I want to add a third column valued as the concatenation of the first and last name called "FullName". How can I accomplish that without losing any data from either of the first two columns?

Comment: where's the second table come in? if you're just concatenating two columns in a table, why not add that as another column?

Comment: Is there a good reason to add a new column? You can just generate the concatenated string on the fly.

Comment: its only one table but a new column that is combined.

Comment: @StampinStephie you originally had a couple typos in your question where you said "table" instead of "column." That's where that comment came from. I edited the question, though, so they're fixed now.

Comment: thanks Matthew! its been a long day

Comment: Please note: "generating the concatenated string on the fly" from @shree.pat18 is the preferred way, because then your data doesn't get out-of-date.
If you write it once now and someone does a name change in your DB, then your FullNames will be out of date.  Also, you are duplicating data - which you should never do.  By concatinating the result "on the fly" you're essentially just referencing the base data, so you keep ONE-AND-ONLY-ONE copy of the master data.  That way if it gets updated, you get the updates.

Answer (score 20):

*Quick preface: this answer was based on the originally incorrect tag that this question was relating to SQL Server. I'm no longer aware of its validity on Oracle SQL Developer.*

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD FullName AS (FirstName + ' ' + LastName)
```

Although in practice I'd advise that you do that operation in your `SELECT`. That's somewhat personal preference, but I tend to think doing things in your end queries is a bit cleaner, more readable, and easier to maintain than storing extra, calculated columns.

**Edit:**

This was eventually found as the answer, and listed by the OP as a comment on this post. The following is appropriate syntax for Oracle Sql Database.

```
ALTER TABLE emps MODIFY (FULL_NAME VARCHAR2(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (first_name || ' ' || last_name) VIRTUAL);
```

Comment: ok i did that and it looked like it added it but when i did a select to display it, i got invalid number
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
SELECT full_name
FROM EMPS
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @StampinStephie Interesting. I don't even recognize the syntax of that error... What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: its SQL developer 4.0.2.15

Comment: That sure sounds like an Oracle Server, not Microsoft SQL Server as you tagged. I'm not familiar with the syntax for Oracle SQL. What happens when you do a select with a similar column? `SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName FROM EMPS`

Comment: i get the proper output with out the "full name". the column is named FIRST_NAME||''||LAST_NAME

Comment: sorry i tagged thw wrong thing, new here. its Oracle SQL developer

Comment: @StampinStephie No problem. I fixed the tag for you as well. I see you marked Jacky's answer as accepted, did that work for you, then?

Comment: no sorry, it didn't. I unmarked it. thanks for all your help.

Comment: So wait, you haven't found your solution? Just to be clear? If not, I'd try the same syntax as I posed in my answer, but using the double-pipe operator rather than plus signs. It seems that's what Oracle SQL uses as a concatenation operator.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. no solution yet. I can do this

SELECT emps.first_name || ' ' || emps.last_name AS FULL_NAME
FROM emps; 

and get the correct column output but its not creating a new column. when i try to do this


SELECT employee_id,FULL_NAME,salary,department_id
FROM EMPS
ORDER BY last_name;

it shows up as a column but no data. and I have also done an ALTER TABLE to add it as a column.

Comment: @StampinStephie I'll look a bit into the documentation. I haven't found a single reference to calculated columns in Oracle yet, though. Which is kind of strange.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you're looking to do this as a computed column as compared to explicitly in your `SELECT`s?

Comment: Aha! (I think). According to [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/rdb/automatic-columns-132042.pdf), the syntax is `...FullName COMPUTED BY first_name||' '||last_name`.

Comment: Hi Matthew. I got a solution for the virtual column, I needed to do this:
ALTER TABLE EMPS
  MODIFY (
          FULL_NAME     VARCHAR2(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (first_name || ' ' || last_name) VIRTUAL
          );

thanks again for all your help!

Comment: it's not working properly, i used `ALTER TABLE cars ADD FullName varchar(500) AS (concat(\`FirstName\`,'-',\`LastName\`));`

Answer (score 6):

If you need fullname column all time when you select from database then you can create computed column at the time of creation of your table employee.

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
  FirstName VARCHAR(20),
  LastName VARCHAR(20),
  FullName AS CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName)
)

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('Rocky','Jeo')

SELECT * FROM Employee 

  Output:

  FirstName  LastName  FullName
  Rocky      Jeo       Rocky Jeo
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your purpose, whether you really need to add a new column to your database, or you just need to query out the "full name" on an as-needed basis.

To view it on the fly, just run the query

`SELECT firstname + ' ' + lastname AS FullName FROM employees`

Beyond that, you also can create a simple Stored Procedure to store it.

Answer (score 0):

(For single result use equal to in the where condition)

```
select * 
from TABLE_name 
where (Column1+Column2) in (11361+280,11365+250)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jacky 's answer, if you are trying to add this to a query and not the table, there is also the CONCAT() function that you can use in the select statement

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as FullName
FROM table_name
```

Comment: you will need to concatenate `' '` too, else it will return `JohnSmith` without a space. e.g `SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as FullName From Table_name`