# What's wrong with my `ALTER TABLE` statement?

Tags: sql-server

I keep receiving the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'as'.

**My code**

```
ALTER TABLE [SupplierDetails]

ADD [practice] varchar(300) as CONCATENATE(SupplierDescription, SupplierEmail)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any SQL Server function called `CONCATENATE()` although there is one called `CONCAT()`.  In any case, you can just use the plus operator to achieve what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE [SupplierDetails]
ADD [practice] as (SupplierDescription + SupplierEmail)
```

As [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729372/add-a-column-that-represents-a-concatenation-of-two-other-varchar-columns) mentions, you might be better off handling the concatenation in a `SELECT` or `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: thanks.  I think something else is going on though i keep getting same error.  using sql server 2012

Comment: Try removing the column type definition from the `ALTER TABLE` statement.  All the examples I see follow this pattern when using an alias.

Answer (score 0):

First of all CONCATENATE(SupplierDescription, SupplierEmail) this is not a valid function in SQL server.

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE [SupplierDetails]

ADD [practice] varchar(300) 

update SupplierDetails
set practice=SupplierDescription + SupplierEmail
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE [SupplierDetails]

ADD [practice] AS (SupplierDescription + SupplierEmail)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ALTER TABLE [SupplierDetails]
ADD [practice] AS CONCAT(SupplierDescription,' ',SupplierEmail)
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE [SupplierDetails]
ADD [practice] AS (SupplierDescription+SupplierEmail)
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE [SupplierDetails]
ADD [practice] AS CONCAT(SupplierDescription,SupplierEmail)
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to create a computed column, which is fine.

The issue is that SQL Server doesn't have a function, called `CONCATENATE`, you either need to use a [`+`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862(v=sql.80).aspx) sign, or use [`CONCAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx). In order to make your `ALTER TABLE` statement correct, you have to do this:

If your SQL Server version is 2008 R2 or older, which doesn't support `CONCAT()`:

```
ALTER TABLE SupplierDetails
ADD practice AS LEFT(SupplierDescription + SupplierEmail, 300);
```

If you're using SQL Server 2012 and beyond:

```
ALTER TABLE SupplierDetails
ADD practice AS LEFT(CONCAT(SupplierDescription, SupplierEmail), 300);
```

Keep in mind that computed columns have to be persisted, that's why I'm adding `LEFT(xxx, 300);`, to make sure that your computed column won't be longer than 300 characters.

Please see this in action:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/429734/computed-column