# Is it possible to concatenate a string to a sequence value and use as a column default value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, tsql-sequence

I'd like to set a default value for a column from a sequence like what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413383/sequence-as-default-value-for-a-column), but also prepend a value in front of the sequence so the value saved in the table looks like `P123`. Is that possible?

Comment: would the letter always be P? Regardless, I don't think you can keep the sequence as an int. I'd virtualize another column based off your sequence columns.

Comment: @scsimon, in this case, yes it'd always be "P". By virtualize, do you mean like a computed column? Would I need two columns to do that (one for the sequence and one for the computed value)? Or how would that look?

Comment: correct on both. Sequence column would need to stay an int and the computed column would be a concatenation of this column and P.  something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/24729386/6167855

Comment: @scsimon, I just learned that I won't be able to do that because we will have to back-fill existing values from another system. So it needs to be a default value that we can explicitly set if there's an existing value.

Comment: @scsimon, nevermind. I reread through that post in my question and it appears that since the column just uses the sequence value as a default, an explicit value can still be added to that column and then the computed column will pick it up.

Comment: Oh nice, I did t see that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's totally possible.
Changing the example from the post you've linked to something like this:

```
create sequence mainseq as bigint start with 1 increment by 1;

create table mytable (
    id      varchar(20) not null constraint DF_mytblid default 'p' + CAST(next value for mainseq as varchar(10)),
    code    varchar(20) not null
)
```

Test:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Code) VALUES ('asdf'), ('cvnb')

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```

Results:

```
id  code
p1  asdf
p2  cvnb
```

Comment: So I don't even need a computed column? Nice.